# How do I listen for file change with requests?

Tags: python

I wanted to make a website to allow anyone to change my sun amount in plants vs zombies. I kinda did that with long polling and basically dossing my website. So I'm wondering, how can I listen for file changes without doing too many requests?

This is my horrible code:

```
val = int(requests.get("https://link.to/my_file.txt").text)
    prevVal = val
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(requests.get("https://link.to/my_file.txt").text)
            if (prevVal != val):
                prevVal = val
                time.sleep(5)
                print(val)
                process.write(sun_pointer, val)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
            print("Timeout :)")
            continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit()
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand, but you're looking for a way to get this info without polling?

Comment: Is this actually causing issues for your site, or you want to preemptively optimize this just in case? If the server and the script are under your control, maybe the script could instead listen for a connection from the server, and the server pings the script every time there's a change? Seems like that would potentially take the load off of your server but I'm no networking expert.

Comment: it is causing issues to my site. When I run it, it sometimes becomes unavailable until I close the script

Comment: Yes I am looking for a way to get the info without polling

Comment: you can't get new information without sending new request. And if this block server then problem can be sever. Did you wrote server code? Did you use threading or multiprocessing to work with many clients?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an endpoint on your server which lets you ask "did the file change since time X" with it just responding with a true/false, and not the entire file every time. That could already reduce a lot of load on your server.

Alternatively, you could create some kind of protocol where clients can connect to a site and keep a socket connection alive between your client and the server, which the server can then use to *send messages back* to your client whenever the file changes, instead of your client constantly polling.

Both solutions require you to modify the server if that's even possible, and the socket one is not very straightforward to get right either.